# Problema con carga de imágenes con PHP // $_FILES

Tags: php

Tengo un problema con `PHP $_FILES` o tambien puede que sea un problema de formato de imagen

el principal problema es el siguiente: tengo dos imagenes diferentes con formato .jpg

> black1.jpg
>
> black2.jpg

`black2.jpg` se sube normalmente sin problemas a mi directorio de imágenes y se carga la dirección en la base de datos.

`black1.jpg` me devuelve el error:

> Notice: Undefined index: archivo in
>   C:\wamp\www\c_blink\php\model_submit_es.php on line 737

`if(!isset($_FILES["archivo"]["name"][0])){`

En el código dejo comentado cual es la linea 737 que trae el error...

Se que el problema es la imagen pero como este sistema va a ser usado por usuarios que pueden cargar muchas imágenes al mismo tiempo puede traerles problemas a la hora de cargar este tipo de imágenes.

El siguiente codigo es mi form:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'?s=4' ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="inscripcion">
<input  type="file" id="file" name="archivo[]" multiple="multiple" class="inputfile inputfile-6" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected"  />
<input type="submit" value="Aceptar & Continuar" name="su"  class="btn-info btn" id="alt">
```

El código PHP que realiza el alta en la base de datos y la carga de imagenes en el directorio:

```
$code=$_SESSION['code'];

 if ($_SESSION['gender']=='mujer') {
    if (!file_exists("../images/model_photos/female/". $code."/")) {
    mkdir("../images/model_photos/female/". $code."/");
}
    $carpetaDestino="../images/model_photos/female/". $code."/";
    }else{
        if (!file_exists("../images/model_photos/male/". $code."/")) {
    mkdir("../images/model_photos/male/". $code."/");
     }
    $carpetaDestino="../images/model_photos/male/". $code."/";
 }
 echo '<div class="rad">';
    # si hay algun archivo que subir
    if(!isset($_FILES["archivo"]["name"][0])) // linea 737 Notice: Undefined index: archivo on line 737
    {


    # recorremos todos los arhivos que se han subido
    for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["archivo"]["name"]);$i++)
    {

        # si es un formato de imagen
        if($_FILES["archivo"]["type"][$i]=="image/jpeg" || $_FILES["archivo"]["type"][$i]=="image/pjpeg" || $_FILES["archivo"]["type"][$i]=="image/gif" || $_FILES["archivo"]["type"][$i]=="image/png")
        {

            # si exsite la carpeta o se ha creado
            if(file_exists($carpetaDestino) || @mkdir($carpetaDestino))
            {
                $origen=$_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"][$i];
                $destino=$carpetaDestino.$_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$i];

                # movemos el archivo
                if(@move_uploaded_file($origen, $destino))
                {
              //echo "<br>".$_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$i]." movido correctamente"; 


                      if ($_SESSION['gender']=='mujer') {
                            $img='images/model_photos/female/'. $code.'/'.$_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$i];
                     }elseif ($_SESSION['gender']=='hombre') {
                            $img='images/model_photos/male/'. $code.'/'.$_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$i];
                      }
                      $code=$_SESSION['code'];

                        $alta_img="INSERT INTO model_page (code,img) VALUES ('$code','$img')";

                        $result=mysql_query($alta_img);

                      ?>

                      <?php
                }else{
                    echo "<br>No se ha podido mover el archivo: ".$_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$i];
                }
            }else{
                echo "<br>No se ha podido crear la carpeta: up/".$user;
            }
        }else{
           echo "<br>".$_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$i]." - NO es imagen jpg";
        }
    }
}else{
    echo "<br>No se ha subido ninguna imagen";
     echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=./model_submit_es.php?s=3">';
     echo "</h3>";
}
```

Comment: En la linea del error prueba a quitar el [0] y quita el ! del isset. Si quieres comprobar que existe con el ! le estas diciendo que entre cuando no exista. Supongo que habra sido un error involuntario.

Comment: Realiza un `var_dump($_FILES["archivo"])` o un `echo '<pre>'.print_r($_FILES["archivo"],true).'</pre>'` para poder debugar de que forma te viene informado el array. Por que el error que comentas es un problema que la key del array `$_FILES["archivo"]["name"]` no existe y por este motivo te da error.

Answer (score 1):

intenta con este codigo

```
 $code=$_SESSION['code'];

 if ($_SESSION['gender']=='mujer') {
    if (!file_exists("../images/model_photos/female/". $code."/")) {
    mkdir("../images/model_photos/female/". $code."/");
}
    $carpetaDestino="../images/model_photos/female/". $code."/";
    }else{
        if (!file_exists("../images/model_photos/male/". $code."/")) {
    mkdir("../images/model_photos/male/". $code."/");
     }
    $carpetaDestino="../images/model_photos/male/". $code."/";
 }
 echo '<div class="rad">';
    # si hay algun archivo que subir
    if(isset($_FILES["archivo"]["name"])) // linea 737 Notice: Undefined index: archivo on line 737
    {


    # recorremos todos los arhivos que se han subido
    for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["archivo"]["name"]);$i++)
    {

        # si es un formato de imagen
        if($_FILES["archivo"]["type"][$i]=="image/jpeg" || $_FILES["archivo"]["type"][$i]=="image/pjpeg" || $_FILES["archivo"]["type"][$i]=="image/gif" || $_FILES["archivo"]["type"][$i]=="image/png")
        {

            # si exsite la carpeta o se ha creado
            if(file_exists($carpetaDestino) || @mkdir($carpetaDestino))
            {
                $origen=$_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"][$i];
                $destino=$carpetaDestino.$_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$i];

                # movemos el archivo
                if(@move_uploaded_file($origen, $destino))
                {
              //echo "<br>".$_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$i]." movido correctamente"; 


                      if ($_SESSION['gender']=='mujer') {
                            $img='images/model_photos/female/'. $code.'/'.$_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$i];
                     }elseif ($_SESSION['gender']=='hombre') {
                            $img='images/model_photos/male/'. $code.'/'.$_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$i];
                      }
                      $code=$_SESSION['code'];

                        $alta_img="INSERT INTO model_page (code,img) VALUES ('$code','$img')";

                        $result=mysql_query($alta_img);

                      ?>

                      <?php
                }else{
                    echo "<br>No se ha podido mover el archivo: ".$_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$i];
                }
            }else{
                echo "<br>No se ha podido crear la carpeta: up/".$user;
            }
        }else{
           echo "<br>".$_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$i]." - NO es imagen jpg";
        }
    }
}else{
    echo "<br>No se ha subido ninguna imagen";
     echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=./model_submit_es.php?s=3">';
     echo "</h3>";
}
```

Comment: Favor de indicar qué diferencia hay entre este código y el que brinda el (la) autor(a) original. Adicional a ello, explicar por qué el código provisto aquí funciona.

Comment: la condicional isset estaba mal formulada

Comment: para más detalles de por qué a veces existe el indice [0] y a veces no http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php#118858